# Animate scrollLeft of a container from point A to B

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

I have a scrollable container whose `scrollLeft` changes from the `currentValue` to `currentValue + 10` on each `requestAnimationFrame` tick (read interval).

However, this transition produces a staggered effect leading to the scrolling happening in an instant instead of animating from `currentValue` to `currentValue + 10`. Is there a way to define an easing function in this case just like we do for transitions?

Also, I need to do this without jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, but you need to know the percentage of how far the animation has gone. Here is a simple method for animations that takes in an object with callbacks and animation duration in seconds.

```
/**
* @param callbackObj Object An object with callbacks in .start, .progress, and .done
* @param duration Integer Total duration in seconds
*/
function animate(callbackObj, duration) {
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
        var startTime = 0, percentage = 0, animationTime = 0;

        duration = duration*1000 || 1000;

        var animation = function(timestamp) {

          if (startTime === 0) {
              startTime = timestamp;
            } else {
              animationTime = timestamp - startTime;
            }

          if (typeof callbackObj.start === 'function' && startTime === timestamp) {
             callbackObj.start();

             requestAnimationFrame(animation);
          } else if (animationTime < duration) {
             if (typeof callbackObj.progress === 'function') {
               percentage = animationTime / duration;
               callbackObj.progress(percentage);
             }

            requestAnimationFrame(animation);
          } else if (typeof callbackObj.done === 'function'){
              callbackObj.done();
          }
        };

      return requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
```

You then combine this method with Robert Penner's Easing Functions: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

```
function easeInOutQuad(t) { return t<.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t },
```

And a final method could look something like this:

```
function sideScroll(rangeInPixels) {
  var element = document.getElementById('scrollableContainer');

  if (element) {
    var sequenceObj = {};
    var seconds = 0.3;
    var startingScrollPosition = element.scrollY;

    sequenceObj.progress = (function(percentage) {
      element.scroll( (startingScrollPosition + easeInOutQuad(percentage))*rangeInPixels) , 0);
    }

    animate(sequenceObj, seconds);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a missing `)` in the sideScroll after `sequenceObj.progress`