# How to Animate Scroll to Top JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have got 2 websites with the same function. It works on one of the websites, doesn't work on the other.

`script.js`:

```
function scrollToTop(){
var timerHandle = setInterval(function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop != 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop != 0)
  window.scrollBy(0,-50); else clearInterval(timerHandle); },10);
}
```

`HTML`

```
       <ul class="footer-navigation">
        <li><a class="back" id="backtoTop" onclick="scrollToTop();return false;"href="#">&uarr;Back to Top</a></li>
        <li><a class="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="about" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
```

It doesn't hit any error but it seems as though it is "counting". When I `console.log` it there's a number in the console next to the logged `counting` but function never executes.

Comment: Looks like your script is working fine.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it works. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: It doesn't scroll to the top basically. When looking at the bottom of page, when hitting scroll to top can see a message at the bottom left saying:  file:///C:/users/documents/website/index.html#. My website at the moment is locally saved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that you shouldn't scroll via a `setInterval` but through `requestAnimationFrame` to avoid jankiness in the scroll. A simple solution to your problem would also to use CSS to make your scrolling smooth. However, this affects all scrolling.

```js
function scrollToTop(){
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 150vh"> 
scroll down
</div>

           <ul class="footer-navigation">
            <li><a class="back" id="backtoTop" onclick="scrollToTop()"href="#">&uarr;Back to Top</a></li>
            <li><a class="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="about" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

More about requestforanimationframe:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46072227/5526624

Comment: Thanks! Can see visibly works, just doesn't work on mine. Starting to wonder if this has anything to do with my html

Comment: html,body{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

  }

The above is the only thing I have

Comment: that was the solution - removed overflow and has worked! thanks Rickard!

Comment: just have a problem now is that on mobile version got a blank margin which overflow-x - hidden was resolving

Answer (score 49):

Try this:

```js
function scrollToTop(){
  window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 150vh"> 
scroll down
</div>

           <ul class="footer-navigation">
            <li><a class="back" id="backtoTop" onclick="scrollToTop();return false;"href="#">&uarr;Back to Top</a></li>
            <li><a class="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="about" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

To complete the previous answers, we can use the following code to the CSS so as not to forget accessibility ;

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: auto;
  }
}
```

Indeed, there are people who have [disorders of the vestibular systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibular_system) and who have configured their browser to reduce animations and movements

Comment: Really good point. Ignoring users who prefer reduced motion is too commonly overlooked.

Answer (score -2):

```
(function($){
    'use strcit';

    $.ScrollUpToTop = function(options){

        // Default options
        options = $.extend({}, options);

        // Variables
        var $btnScroll = $("<button id=\"ScrollUpToTop\">^</button>").hide();
        var $body = $(document.body);

        // insert scroll up to top button
        $($body).append($btnScroll);

        // attach click event on button
        $($btnScroll).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $($body).animate(
                {scrollTop:0},
                800
            );
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $($btnScroll).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $($btnScroll).fadeOut();
            }
        });

    };

    $.ScrollUpToTop();

})(jQuery);
```

Please follow this link.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Super-Simple-Scroll-Up-To-Top-Plugin-with-jQuery/

and you can also get reference from using source.

view-source:https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Super-Simple-Scroll-Up-To-Top-Plugin-with-jQuery/

Comment: JQuery isn't needed nowadays. Javascript's DOM manipulation has caught up.