# How do I add 'Easing' into this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm hoping to add an Ease In into this timed function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showit() {document.getElementById("introText").style.display = "block";}
setTimeout("showit()", 1500); 
</script>
```

I'm not quite sure how I would do that though! Can I add it to the function somewhere by its id?

Absolute beginner to JS and just try to piece it all together so any info would be appreciated!!

Comment: Assuming you want to go from `display: none` to `display: block` in an easing way, no. It's either visible or not.

Comment: you'de probably better handle that kind of thing with CSS..

Comment: You can only animate numbers (integers, floats, colors), where display: none --> block are no numbers. You should do the animation with CSS by adding a class that changes the opacity or whatnot, but if you still want to animate using javascript, you need to use `requestAnimationFrame`. I've written a previous answer to show how that can look like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46072227/5526624

Answer (score 0):

You cant actually ease that CSS property because it is not a number. What you would have to do is show the element first, then animate the opacity. Here is a javascript solution which does not work in IE.

[Element.animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

[Animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

[EffectTiming object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming)

Basically the animate method animates enumerable CSS values from a start to an end value. The method accepts 2 arguments, an array of objects which represent keyframes in the animation, and another object containing timing options like easing, and fill. There is a lot you can do with this method so i'd suggest reading through the documentation.

```js
// change display value
document.getElementById("test-obj").style.display = "flex";

// animate
document.getElementById("test-obj").animate([
  // keyframes
  { opacity: 1 }  
], {
  // timing options
  duration: 1500,
  fill: "forwards",
  easing: "ease-out"
});
```

```css
#test-obj {
  display:none;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:white;
  background: slategray;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-obj">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding inline style like that, add a class that has everything defined already including your easing. Since the element used in the example is a div, there is no need to add the default rule for *display* **block**, once we remove the class that has `display: none` it reverts to block by default. Set up a setTimeout to remove the class with `display: none` that sets the interval to that of your animation in CSS => 2s =>, JS => 2000.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("introText")
const btn = document.getElementById("showit")

function showMyDiv(){  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    if(!el.classList.contains('none')){
      setTimeout(()=>{
        el.classList.add('none')
      , 2000})
    }else{
      el.classList.remove('none')
    }
  },10)
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showMyDiv)
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}

#introText {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: show 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="introText" class="none">
  Here is some intro text I want to show with an easing animation
</div>

<button id="showit">show it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate between:

- `display: none;`
- `display: block;`

So, consider using an alternative to `display` like `opacity`.

You can straightforwardly transition from:

```
.introText.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

to:

```
.introText {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Then, all the javascript needs to do is remove the `.hide` class.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const introText = document.querySelector('.introText');

const toggleText = () => {
  introText.classList.remove('hide');
}

setTimeout(toggleText, 500);
```

```css
.introText {
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.introText.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="introText hide">This text appears after 1.5 seconds.</p>
```